# In C++ if a member function is virtual when can static binding be used?

Tags: c++, binding, static

In C++ when can a virtual function use static binding? If it is being accessed through a pointer, accessed directly, or never?

Answer (score 9):

When a virtual method is called through a pointer or reference, dynamic binding is used.  Any other time, compile-time binding is used. Ex:

```
class C;

void Foo(C* a, C& b, C c) {
  a->foo();  // dynamic
  b.foo();  // dynamic
  c.foo();  // static (compile-time)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call the base class version of a function, you can do that by explicitly naming the base class:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual ~Base() {}
  virtual void DoIt() { printf("In Base::DoIt()\n"); }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  virtual void DoIt() { printf("In Derived::DoIt()\n"); }
};

Base *basePtr = new Derived;
basePtr->DoIt();  // Calls Derived::DoIt() through virtual function call
basePtr->Base::DoIt();  // Explicitly calls Base::DoIt() using normal function call
delete basePtr;
```

Comment: Hah, I was in the middle of typing almost the exact same post! Upvoted yours.

Answer (score 2):

Static binding can only be done when the object's type is totally unambiguous at compile time. I can only think of four places where an abstract object's type is unambiguous: in the constructor, in the destructor, when declared locally and within the same scope as a dynamic allocation. I don't know the standard that well so I couldn't say what it says about those four possibilities (I'd say the first two are statically bound, the third possible statically bound and the last not; although it probably says it's undefined or implementation dependent). Other than those points, the object being accessed through a base class pointer could be pointing to a derived class and the current translation unit has no way of knowing, so static binding is not possible. The function could be called with a pointer to the base class in one instance and a pointer to a derived class in another!

Comment: The optimizer may fuse different scopes via inlining. If the type is known in one of these scopes, it will be known in the fused scope.